# Smarty fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am using the following code

```
require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty;
$sel=mysql_query("select id, name from form");  
$smarty->assign('contact', $db->getRow($sql));
$smarty->display('testfunction.tpl');
```

I am getting error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getRow() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\testfun.php on line 21
```

Comment: Its not a smarty error, but PHP one. The `$db` is not an object - it was not initialized or assigned to an object. Do you expect to be something in `$db` or you just copied-pasted in from somewhere?

Comment: yes i removed the db now it is working with $smarty->assign('contact', mysql_fetch_row($sel));

I have template file 
<ul>
{foreach from=$contact item=foo}
    <li>{$foo}</li>
{/foreach}
 
i want output like :
1:a
2:b
how can i do that ?
</ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared any $db object.
Use this instead:

```
$smarty->assign('contact', mysql_fetch_row($sel));
```

Comment: yes i removed the db now it is working with $smarty->assign('contact', mysql_fetch_row($sel));

I have template file 
<ul>
{foreach from=$contact item=foo}
    <li>{$foo}</li>
{/foreach}
 
i want output like :
1:a
2:b
how can i do that ?
</ul>

Comment: @user1132887 the reason that it didn't work wasn't the fact that you called `$db->getRow($sql)` inside `$smarty->assign()` - it was the fact that you misspelled `$sql` as `$sel`. Try it again with the correct parameter name and you'll see that it works!